# Adding Image in Google+ Integration

Tags: javascript, google-api

I have integrated Google+ to my visualforce page and it's working fine. I want to display the image which is a url field, dynamically in my `object{!obj.image}`. How do I do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script');po.type='text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
     })();
</script>
```

i have achieved displaying image by redirecting to the detail page where the images exist by

```
          <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.mywebsite/detailpage" />
```

but it is displaying all the images of the page like gallery i want first image only how do i do this??

Comment: i have tried gapi.post.render("widget-div", {'href' : 'https://plus.google.com/109813896768294978296/posts/hdbPtrsqMXQ'} );

Answer (score 0):

we can not send images to google+ sharing.It takes images from the page by default